# Which Design Pattern to Use? (Showing different graphics at client side according to different graphic apis)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a database layer at my application. At my front side I have graphics to show users. I get necessary data from database and show that data at web site. When I get raw data from database I process that data for which API I use (highcharts etc.). I designed something like that:

```
ChartDTO
```

The main interface for all chart implementations. Has methods as like:

```
public Object getTotalUsersPieChart(DatabaseData databaseData);
```

and

```
HighChartsDTOImpl
```

An implementation of ChartDTO. All its methods returns Object type variables.

At client side I directly feed my graphics with the data coming from server side without needing any pre-process at client side.

**My question is that:**
I know there is a design mistake here and maybe it is not a DTO design (at least my architecture says that)

How I could design that scenario?

Comment: are you having some trouble with this design?

Comment: if looking for details of DTO
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx 
this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use some sort of [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) pattern. 
You should pass the client a "hint" on the type of chart you want to create, 
And have a ChartFactory create it for you. 
Here is a code snippet:

```
public class ChartFactory {
    
    public Chart createChart(ChartType, ChartParameters params) {
       Chart chart = ... //Creates a chart object based on type and ChartParameters
       return chart;
    }
}
```

You can have this factory to be a Singleton, 
 so if you need to do some factory initializing, you will do that only once.
ChartParameters should hold parameters for creating an object of specific chart type. 
It can be a simple map of keys and value, i.e look like:

```
public class ChartParameters {
    private Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public Object getParam(String paramName) {
        return params.get(paramName);
    }

    //Add here more methods... maybe a CTOR that takes a map of params,
    //And a method to add a parameter
}
```

Or this can have another implementation.
You may also decide to have parameter class per each one of the subclasses of Chart (all these parameter classes will extend ChartParameters), 
But this may cause you some sort of duplication at the inheritance tree. 
To conclude, 
In this way all you need to send to the client is the chart type, and the parameters, and it will instantiate that proper chart object.

Comment: Thanks, this makes more clear everything. However is it a problem that I will return different type of objects for different type APIs. i.e. if I use Higcharts api, I will return an object that has members data and value, if I use another API I will use another fields. Also within highcharts API I will have different type of return types if I get pie chart or line chart or column chart or combo chart etc. (For all APIs it is a common that return may be column chart, pie chart, combo chart or line chart) How to design with this needs?

Comment: You can have abstraction over various APIs and work with your objects.. I would recommend you read about Facade and Adatper patterns.

Comment: using adapter or factory which one do you suggest for situation?

Comment: Both. You can use more than one pattern in a design. The factory will create objects based on chart type. These objects will be adapters to various APIs as you mentioned - for example, let's say that you're using 3 diffrerent APIs and in each one of them you have different method for "draw" - you can have a chart-adapter object with a "uniform" draw method, and based on its concrete type it will use one of the APIs.

Comment: .... but in case of protocol changes, it can help you to quickly adapt to the new protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you was a factor pattern or even an abstract factory pattern.  Using this factory you can generate the appropriate components configured for the look-and-feel you want.

Comment: How can I handle that situation: I have different type of return objects for different apis(the only common thing is that they return pie chart, column chart and combo chart but has different representations and attributes)

Comment: I would have Factory(s) which can return a superset of all the things you might need and some Factory methods might return `null` or `UnsupportedOperationException`